# Passing variable is not working in postgres sql

Tags: psql

```
     PGPASSWORD=$PPASSWORD psql -h $PG_HOST -U $PUSERNAME -p $PG_PORT -d $PG_DB << EOF

     \i /dbf/appworx/pgsql/$1.sql $2;
```

it giving error like \i: extra argument "232;" ignored

Comment: ./Test.ksh Raise_Notice_Testscript 232

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.